# Try to get ObjectInputStream from Server (TCP) to deserialize objects

Tags: java, serialization, tcp, client-server, deserialization

I basically want to send an arraylist from Server to my client and it has to be serialized so I'm using ObjectI/OStream. But this is by first time creating a client/server program so I don't really know how to do it. I can't even construct the ObjectInputStream constructor in the client program. I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>       at SalesServer.main(SalesServer.java:35)

Code:

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
  import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.net.UnknownHostException;
  import java.util.Scanner;


  public class SalesClient {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Socket ssocket = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    ObjectInputStream inp = null;
    Scanner in = null;

    try {
        ssocket = new Socket("FahadAhmed-PC", 6667);
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        inp = new ObjectInputStream();

    }catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: FahadAhmed-PC");
        System.exit(1);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

}
```

Server code. First it scans a text file and then adds a sales object to arraylist:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SalesServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6667);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 5555.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try{
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    ArrayList<Sales> salesList = getSalesList();

    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

}

private static ArrayList<Sales> getSalesList() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Sales> list = new ArrayList<Sales>(10);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sales.txt")));
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String state;
        int q1, q2, q3, q4;
        state = in.nextLine();
        q1 = in.nextInt();
        q2 = in.nextInt();
        q3 = in.nextInt();
        q4 = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        Sales sale = new Sales(state, q1, q2, q3, q4);
        System.out.println(sale.toString());
        list.add(sale);
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: What version of JDK are you using?  If your using JDK7 then I can give you an sample using NIO2 which performs better than blocking

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty good example about sockets programming http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm.

Comment: Without an ObjectOutputStream in it. Not an answer.

Comment: You have only to change `DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());` on `ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream (server.getOutputStream());`

Comment: So incorporate that into your answer, but none of that will accomplish writing of objects, which is the topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your client code doesn't compile.
2. It exits before doing any I/O, which closes the socket, which causes the exception at the other end.